# Need help seeing if my methodology for this DE works.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the General Solution of the DE (Primes denote derivatives with respect to x): $y'=(xy'+y)y^3$

$y'= xy'y^3+y^4$

$y'-xy'y^3=y^4$

$y'(1-xy^3)=y^4$

$y' = \cfrac {y^4}{1-xy^3}$

Let's set x as the dependent variable and y as the independent variable

then

$x' = \cfrac {1-xy^3}{y^4} = \cfrac {1}{y^4} - \cfrac{x}{y}$

Rearranging gives us

$x'+\frac xy = \cfrac {1}{y^4}$

Now we have it in the form of a first order linear DE!

$P(x) = 1/y$

The integration factor now needs to be calculated

$p(x) = e^\int \frac1ydy = y$

Multiply both sides of the linear DE by the integration factor (y)

$yx'+x=\cfrac {1}{y^5}$

See that the LHS is just the result of the product rule and integrate both sides

$\int (yx)' = \int \cfrac {1}{y^5}$

$yx = \cfrac {-1}{4y^4} + C$

get x by itself

$x = \cfrac {-1}{4y^5} + \frac cy$

This is the final answer

Is my reasoning correct? Did I go wrong somewhere?

Thank You For Any Help/Comments

Comment: The answer should be $$x=\dfrac C y-\dfrac 1 {2y^3}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More simply:
$$y'=(xy'+y)y^3$$
$$\dfrac {y'}{y^3}=(xy)'$$
$$-\dfrac 12\left (\dfrac {1}{y^2} \right )'=(xy)'$$
You have deritavites on both sides just integrate. The answer should be: $$x(y)=\dfrac C y-\dfrac 1 {2y^3}$$

---

You made a mistake here:
$$yx'+x=\cfrac {1}{y^5}$$
It should be:
$$yx'+x=\cfrac {1}{y^3}$$
Since you multiplied this line by $y$:
$$x'+\dfrac xy=\dfrac {1}{y^4}$$

Comment: Thank You. I figured out my arithmetic error and got the same answer. Just a quick question with ODE's in general to help further my understand. Does it matter whether you solve for x or y? I always assumed that you should solve for the dependent variable ((x) in this case). But could you solve for the independent variable ((y in this case)) instead and STILL have it be a General Solution? I.E. Does it matter whether you solve for a independent or dependent variable for a General Solution. I always believed that it should be the dependent variable you solve for.

Comment: Also another GS for this solution would be 1/(2y^2) + xy = C as it's of the form F(x,y) = C correct?

Comment: You are welcome @SleeperMan23 Thats great if you find your mistake. The better is to express the solution as $y(x)= ....$ whenever it is possible but sometimes it's easier to exrepss $x$ as a function of y. Some other times you keep an implicit form as $f(x,y)=C$

Comment: Yes all these exprerssions are correct @SleeperMan23

Comment: Ah so overall it doesn't matter whether you solve for x or y (dependent or independent) or solve for F(x,y) = C. As long as you solve for one of them correct?

Comment: Yes true. Sometimes it's easier to consider $x'$ instead of $y'$ it really depends on the kind of ODE you deal with @SleeperMan23

Comment: Yeah definitely, just go with what's easiest to solve. Got it. Thank You!

Comment: Definitely yes. The easier way the best way @SleeperMan23